# Can't access docker image from EC2 server

Tags: amazon-web-services, solr, amazon-ec2, docker

I've got a standard EC2 Ubuntu server running a basic LAMP stack. I've installed Docker and I'm trying to hook up a solr container (https://github.com/makuk66/docker-solr specificly).

I have the docker image running 

`ce32c020e7da        makuk66/docker-solr   "/bin/bash -c '/opt/   10 minutes ago      Up 10 minutes       0.0.0.0:8983->8983/tcp   solr5`

According to the readme of the solr image I should be able to access the solr admin panel on port 8983

Using the public IP of the EC2 server on port 80 I land on a web page (expected as apache is running) but when trying to access on port [..]:8983 I get 504 Gateway Timeout.

I've allowed all incoming connections on port 8983 for the security group that the EC2 server is a part of but still no luck...

There isn't anything further I should need to do here is there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems internal network is blocking access, this works as expected outside our enterprise network.

Apologies.